# iOS Simulator Quits

Tags: ios, contacts, simulator

All of the sudden I cannot run the iOS Simulator properly.  The built-in apps no longer work (Contacts, Safari, etc.).  I can however build and install my own app.

I attempted to access the contacts app so that I could manually add a contact but then I get the error `"The simulated application quit."`

If I launch the simulator within XCode by running my app, selecting `Hardware > Home`, I can then open the built-in apps, including contacts, but then I cannot add a contact as it crashes.  I reset the simulator, as well as moving the SQL DB for contacts out of the way.

I am running Xcode 4.3.2, and the simulator is located in...

`XCode4 > Platforms > iPhoneSimulator.platform > Developer > Applications`

Any recommendations?  What could suddenly cause this?  The error does not appear to be related to my code since it exists entirely with the simulator at this point.

Note:  I upgraded to Lion from Snow Leopard so that I could run Xcode 4.3.2.  This was a few weeks ago.

`Scenario #1`

1. Reboot
2. Open the iOS Simulator App located at `XCode4 > Platforms > iPhoneSimulator.platform > Developer > Applications`
3. Select any app. For example, the Contacts App or Settings or Safari or Photos.
4. Simulator crashes with the error `"The simulated application quit."`

`Scenario #2`

1. Reboot
2. Open Xcode 4.3.2.
3. Build and run the application I am developing which accesses the contacts app.
4. Application runs
5. Select Hardware > Home
6. Built-in apps open and run fine, EXCEPT the contacts app.
7. Launch contacts app
8. Select the '+' button to add a contact.
9. Try to enter the First Name.
10. Simulator crashes with the error `"The simulated application quit."`

UPDATE: I found a work-around. I should have clarified that I was running in iPad mode with the simulator. I switched to iPhone mode and was able to add a contact with no problems. I then switched back to iPad so that I could continue development. My app is a universal app and has no problems accessing contacts within SDK code. I conclude at the moment that there is either a bug with the simulator with contacts or something got bugged some how. Anyway, I am up and running again. The next step is to update to the latest Xcode 4.3.3. However, I do not want to do so during heavy development. I will update when I am able to.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried uninstalling/reinstalling Xcode and the Developer tools?

Comment: Not yet Erik. I was hoping to find a simpler solution due to time constraints. However, I did find a work-around. See my update above. Thanks for replying.